# SCSS Change Parent Z-Index on Hover

Tags: sass

```
.sidemenu {
  z-index: 5;
  .menudiv {
    &:hover {
      .sidemenu{
          z-index: 999 !important;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

That's my scss code. But .sidemenu's z-index doesn't change. How can I change parent's z-index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector is targeting a sidemenu *inside* a menuitem - not the parent, I guess you want.

```
.sidemenu .menudiv:hover .sidemenu { .... }


<div class="sidemenu">
  <div class="menuitem">
    <div class="sidemenu">
    </div>  
  </div>
</div>
```

In CSS it is not possible to change the styling of a parent item from a child - why you must add the *hover* state to the sidemenu

```
.sidemenu {
  z-index: 5;
  &:hover { z-index: 6; }
}
```

However, (**please note this is a bit hackish**) if you only want the z-index to change if you are hovering *the sidebar* above a nested menuitem you can use pointer-events to disable click/hover interaction on the sidemenu itself and then  re-enable it on menuitems only.

```
.sidemenu {
  z-index: 5;
  pointer-events: none;
  &:hover { z-index: 6; }

  .menuitem {
    pointer-events: auto;
  }
}
```

Now you are still looking for hover on the *sidebar* - but it will only work if the mouse is at a position where pointer-events are not disabled (the nested menuitem).